# SpriteKit side scrolling doesn't update physicsWorld

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Following the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24748247/define-map-bounds-and-center-on-player-node/24843989#24843989) (except in Objective C) and the standard Apple documentation, I discovered that the `physicsWorld` doesn't update its positions when `myWorld` updates its position. I turned on `showsPhysics` on my skView to verify this. See these screenshots.

Before any motion: 
[image: screen 1]
After a little motion 
[image: screen 2]
Getting a little farther 
[image: screen 3]
And just before contact
[image: screen 4]

Here's my code for centering `myWorld`. Most of the length is due to me being extremely verbose in dealing with the edge limits.

```
- (void)centerOnNode:(SKNode *)monkeyNode
{
    CGPoint monkeyPosition = monkeyNode.position;

    // Check if monkey died
    if (monkeyPosition.y < myWorld.frame.origin.y - sceneHeight/2) {
        [self monkeyDied];
    }

    // Check if monkey won
    if (monkeyPosition.x > skyFarRightSide.x) {
        [self monkeyWon:monkeyNode];
    }

    // Define limits
    CGFloat scrollTopLimit = skyFarTopSide.y - sceneHeight/2;
    CGFloat scrollBottomLimit = 0;
    CGFloat scrollLeftLimit = 0;
    CGFloat scrollRightLimit = skyFarRightSide.x - sceneWidth/2;

    // Normal (no limits hit) scrolling
    if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollLeftLimit && monkeyPosition.x < scrollRightLimit && monkeyPosition.y > scrollBottomLimit && monkeyPosition.y < scrollTopLimit) {
        [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-monkeyPosition.x, -monkeyPosition.y)];
    }

    // At far left scrolling
    if (monkeyPosition.x < scrollLeftLimit) {
        // No y limits hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y > scrollBottomLimit && monkeyPosition.y < scrollTopLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, -monkeyPosition.y)];
        }

        // Bottom limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y < scrollBottomLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        }

        // Top limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y > scrollTopLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, -scrollTopLimit)];
        }
    }

    // At far right scrolling
    if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollRightLimit) {
        // No y limits hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y > scrollBottomLimit && monkeyPosition.y < scrollTopLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-scrollRightLimit, -monkeyPosition.y)];
        }

        // Bottom limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y < scrollBottomLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-scrollRightLimit, 0)];
        }

        // Top limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.y > scrollTopLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-scrollRightLimit, -scrollTopLimit)];
        }
    }

    // At far bottom scrolling
    if (monkeyPosition.y < scrollBottomLimit) {
        // No x limits hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollLeftLimit && monkeyPosition.x < scrollRightLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-monkeyPosition.x, 0)];
        }

        // Left limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x < scrollLeftLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
        }

        // Right limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollRightLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-scrollRightLimit, 0)];
        }
    }

    // At far top scrolling
    if (monkeyPosition.y > scrollTopLimit) {
        // No x limits hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollLeftLimit && monkeyPosition.x < scrollRightLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-monkeyPosition.x, -scrollTopLimit)];
        }

        // Left limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x < scrollLeftLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(0, -scrollTopLimit)];
        }

        // Right limit hit
        if (monkeyPosition.x > scrollRightLimit) {
            [myWorld setPosition:CGPointMake(-scrollRightLimit, -scrollTopLimit)];
        }
    }
}
```

Is there an elegant way to fix this? So far my only idea is to include more code in `centerOnNode` that resets the positions of every `physicsBody` in `myWorld`.

Comment: 1 question = did you attached all your physics bodies with myWorld or you attached them with scene.

Comment: The segments of the rope are built up in a subclass but the full rope they create is added to myWorld. All the other nodes are added to myWorld as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what's changed in the last 2 years, but the other answer here didn't work anymore. Instead, now I combine the rope segments position with its parent's (the full rope). So I just do

```
CGPoint convertedRopePosition = CGPointMake(ropePhysicsBody.node.parent.position.x + ropePhysicsBody.node.position.x, ropePhysicsBody.node.parent.position.y + ropePhysicsBody.node.position.y);
SKPhysicsJointPin *jointPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:monkeyPhysicsBody bodyB:ropePhysicsBody anchor:convertedRopePosition];
```

This is needed because the rope segment is placed under the full length of the rope, so it's position is relative to the full rope rather than the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that once the monkey makes contact, all of the physics bodies snap back to their proper locations. However, a joints `anchorPoint` ends up in the wrong place.

I added the following convenience method to my GameScene.m.

```
-(CGPoint)convertSceneToFrameCoordinates:(CGPoint)scenePoint
{
    CGFloat xDiff = myWorld.position.x - self.position.x;
    CGFloat yDiff = myWorld.position.y - self.position.y;
    return CGPointMake(scenePoint.x + self.frame.size.width/2 + xDiff, scenePoint.y + self.frame.size.height/2 + yDiff);
}
```

I use this method to add joints. It handles all of the coordinate system transformations that need to be dealt with that lead to the issue raised in this question. For example, the way I add joints

```
    CGPoint convertedRopePosition = [self convertSceneToFrameCoordinates:ropePhysicsBody.node.position];
    SKPhysicsJointPin *jointPin = [SKPhysicsJointPin jointWithBodyA:monkeyPhysicsBody bodyB:ropePhysicsBody anchor:convertedRopePosition];
    jointPin.upperAngleLimit = M_PI/4;
    jointPin.shouldEnableLimits = YES;
    [self.scene.physicsWorld addJoint:jointPin];
```